# How to check previous array length in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having this issue where I need to check if **previous array length** is the same as the **new array length**.

---

I'm working on a survey that renders questions dynamically.
For example let's say my survey starts with 2 questions, then if I answer question 2 it may or may not show me question number 3, and if it shows me question 3 now my array has 3 elements (each question is an element in my array).

> Does anyone know how to keep track of previous array length and compare it with the new array length.

I've been pulling my hair on this one for a while now. Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's my code:

```
// This is how I get the questions from my survey

var availableQuestions = cmp.items.items.filter(function(group){ return !group.collapsed; });

// This is how I get the number of questions in the array
var numberOfquestions =  availableQuestions.length;
```

The variable **availableQuestions** will always show me the new number of visible questions on the survey, but how to compare it to the previous one and check if I have more questions display on the page or not?

Comment: keep another variable to store it ?

Comment: um `cmp.items.items.length`

Comment: @DhananjaiPai can you provide an example? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filter` method returns a *new* array, it doesn't modify the original. So in your case, you still have access to `cmp.items.items`, which is the original array. So you can simply do:

```
if (availableQuestions.length === cmp.items.items.length) {
  // They're the same length, do whatever.
}
```

Comment: @IceMetallPunk The problem is that I need to use filter in order to filter out the questions that are not collapsed otherwise I will get multiple questions back

Comment: Yes, and? I never said you can't use filter, I just said that the array returned from `filter` is a new array, so you still have access to the old one to compare the lengths :)

Comment: The problem in this case is the previous array may not be the entire array, it may be an array filtered on another condition

Comment: So make a variable to hold the array that you actually want to check? I don't really understand what you're asking. If you're asking how to check the length of an array after you've lost all references to it, that you can't do.